# How do I get the value of a field from an object that has been recently created in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass the primary key of a service object so that I can list all of the fields by redirecting to an html page. I am not sure how to get the value of the primary key of the service object that has just been created.

Below is my view.py

```
def create(request):
    # val= 3
    if request.POST:
        form= ServiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response('services/service_created.html', 
                              {'service_id': request.POST.id}) # THIS CODES IS INCORRECT
    else:
        form = ServiceForm()

    args= {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('services/create_service.html', args )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `save` of the form returns created object. So you can get ID of object:

```
service_obj = form.save() 
...
{'service_id': service_obj.id}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I can't believe I didn't think to create a service_obj variable